# Could not resolve @EJB reference:

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am trying to implement EJBs in my project but keep getting the same error when deploying to JBoss AS 6 (Final).

I have two classes:

```
@Stateless
@Local(ForecastReturnService.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ForecastReturnServiceImpl implements ForecastReturnService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ForecastReturnServiceImpl.class);

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
}
```

and the other EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class CacheManagementServiceImpl implements CacheManagementService {

@EJB
private ForecastReturnService forecastReturnService;
}
```

The error message is with regards to 'forecastReturnService' bean that I am trying to inject:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/webui.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve @EJB reference: [EJB Referenc
e: beanInterface 'com.ls.forecast.jpa.ForecastReturnService', beanName 'null', mappedName 'null', lookupName 'null', owning unit 'ComponentDeploymentContext@16939526{org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBoss
EnterpriseBeanMetaData.CacheManagementServiceImpl}'] for environment entry: env/com.ls.forecast.webui.business.CacheManagementServiceImpl/forecastReturnService in unit ComponentDeploymentContext@16939
526{org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossEnterpriseBeanMetaData.CacheManagementServiceImpl}

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_20]
```

I noticed the following message in the JBoss console:

```
13:34:27,681 WARN  [MappedReferenceMetaDataResolverDeployer] Unresolved references exist in JBossMetaData:[#CacheManagementServiceImpl:AnnotatedEJBReferenceMetaData{name=com.ls.forecast.webui.business
.CacheManagementServiceImpl/forecastReturnService,ejb-ref-type=null,link=null,ignore-dependecy=false,mapped/jndi-name=null,resolved-jndi-name=null,beanInterface=interface com.ls.forecast.jpa.ForecastR
eturnService}, #EntityForecastReturnResultServiceImpl:AnnotatedEJBReferenceMetaData{name=com.ls.forecast.webui.business.EntityForecastReturnResultServiceImpl/entityForecastReturnProcessor,ejb-ref-type
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Seems like I am missing something in the plumbing...

I would like to add that if I add the following to the @EJB annotation, it seems to get rid of the error:

```
@EJB(lookup="com.ls.forecast.jpa.ForecastReturnService/local")
private ForecastReturnService forecastReturnService;
```

Not sure why I would have to specify the local interface since I have seen many examples/tutorials with @EJB only.  Why would I need to specify the local interface?

Answer (score 2):

I've search high an low for this solution, finally got it. First of all we need to be aware of the standard EE 6 (portable JNDI) JNDIs. JBoss documentation sucks. you gotta Hunt for your solution.

Portable JNDI (PREFIXES):

- `java:app` 
   Usable only within an application (i.e an EAR)
- `java:global` 
   Usable from any application in the container (i.e even outside an EAR)
- `java:module` 
   Usable only within an module (i.e an Module - EJB)

lets have a look at the JBoss 6.1.0 JMX Console. 
JMX Console > service=JNDIView (Under JBoss section)

This brings you the JMX MBean View 
Now you can view the JNDI tree by clicking the invoke button `list` row (mine was the last row), you can also us the `listXML` but i found that confusing.

under the `java:` section scroll to the branch that begins with `global` (because we want use the EJB remotely outside the EAR). Judging from the code above you should be able to find a path that goes something like:

global > ForecastReturnServiceEJB (Project name) > ForecastReturnServiceImpl!inject.ForecastReturnService

translate this to:
`java:global/ForecastReturnServiceEJB/ForecastReturnServiceImpl!inject.ForecastReturnService`

This is the JNDI we need to use for global access.

```
 @EJB(mappedName="java:global/ForecastReturnServiceEJB/ForecastReturnServiceImpl!inject.ForecastReturnService")
private ForecastReturnService forecastReturnService;
```

or

```
 @EJB(mappedName="java:app/ForecastReturnServiceEJB/ForecastReturnServiceImpl!inject.ForecastReturnService")
private ForecastReturnService forecastReturnService;
```

One more thing, you can only use `@EJB` without parameters within the same EAR.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by modifying my project so that it is now packaged as an ear instead of a war.  I can now have as many ejb jars as desired although I decided to take this opportunity to re-organize the project and place all EJBs in the same Maven module.

Comment: FYI, I tested in a .war and did not encounter your problem. Maybe you should try to create a complete new war with only the minimum amount of code and see if you still run into the issue. If not, slowly build back to your full code until it breaks again.

Comment: My war was made up of multiple Maven sub modules (jars), which is why it could not bind some of the EJBs but could find others (ie the ones directly under the web module were picked up).

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything specific in the interfaces you implement?

The most straightforward implementation deployed to JBoss AS 6 just works when I quickly tried it locally:

```
package inject;

public interface ForecastReturnService {

}
```

The to be injected bean:

```
package inject;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

@Stateless
@Local(ForecastReturnService.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ForecastReturnServiceImpl implements ForecastReturnService {


}
```

Interface of bean where injection takes place:

```
package inject;

public interface CacheManagementService {

}
```

Bean where injection takes place:

```
package inject;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class CacheManagementServiceImpl implements CacheManagementService {

    @EJB
    private ForecastReturnService forecastReturnService;
}
```

Relevant entries in log:

```
[org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: inject.ForecastReturnServiceImpl ejbName: ForecastReturnServiceImpl
[org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.jndiregistrar.JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    ForecastReturnServiceImpl/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
    ForecastReturnServiceImpl/local-inject.ForecastReturnService - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

and

```
STARTED EJB: inject.CacheManagementServiceImpl ejbName: CacheManagementServiceImpl
[org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.jndiregistrar.JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    CacheManagementServiceImpl/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
    CacheManagementServiceImpl/local-inject.CacheManagementService - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

Two small remarks (not directly related to your question), but `@TransactionAttribute` is not needed here. `REQUIRED` is already the default. `@Local` should be used on the interface, using it on the class level is for legacy interfaces that can't be changed by you.